# Unity C# GameObject Clones Sharing the Same Script When I Don't want them to

Tags: unity, c#

I've been having issues with a game I've been working on for a while. It's a pretty big project. I'm having some issues with two tree prefab game objects sharing code, where I don't want them to.

When the player presses <kbd>E</kbd> while facing them, they start searching the tree for items like apples. It was all working well, until I added another tree. Now, when I search one tree, it searches all trees in the scene. Obviously, I don't want that to happen.

I have provided my code, below. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Search : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public List<Item> items;
    public bool searched = false;
    public GameObject inventory;
    public Inventory inv;
    public Log log;
    public AudioSource takeSFX;
    public GameObject player;

    void Awake()
    {
        inventory = GameObject.Find("  Inventory Master");
        inv = inventory.GetComponent<Inventory>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        log = GameObject.Find("  Game Master").GetComponent<Log>();
        AddItems();
        items = new List<Item>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        SearchObject();
    }

    public void AddItems()
    {
        int rand = (int)Random.Range(0, 2);
        Debug.Log(rand);

        for (int i = 0; i < rand; i++)
        {
            items.Add(inv.database.FetchItemByID(0));
        }
    }

    public void SearchObject()
    { 
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Interact"))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
            Debug.Log("Raycasting");

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 10))
            {
                Debug.Log("Searching");

                if (!searched)
                {
                    this.takeSFX.Play();

                    if (items.Count >= -0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
                        {
                            this.inv.AddItem(items[i].ID);
                        }
                    }    

                    if (items.Count == 0)
                        log.UpdateLog("No items found in search.");
                    else if (items.Count == 1)
                        log.UpdateLog("1 item found in search.");
                    else
                        log.UpdateLog(items.Count + " items found in search.");
                    searched = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this script, *every* tree fires a ray, checks whether that ray hit *something* (not necessarily the tree that's currently running this script, not necessarily a tree at all - you never check *what* the ray hit) then sets its `searched` value to `true`. You probably want the *player character* to fire the ray (so it happens only once - raycasts have some cost) and then search/interact with *the first thing that the ray hit*. That way you can ensure you're only ever searching one thing at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your raycast is being cast for every tree in the scene. Every tree is checking if the raycast hit *something*, even if it's not that tree.

This is happening because you are getting the input event **inside** the tree object.  You should centralize this Event Handler, adding it to inside your PlayerInput.